# How to understand when to use the $ sign with list commands in TCL?

Tags: list, function, scripting, command, tcl

Here we have 3 commands: lindex, lappend and length.

If I want to use them I need to use $ sign with lindex and llength, but I do not need to use it with lappend.

Look at the following codes:

```
set list_name {1 2 3 4 5}
puts [lindex $list_name 1]
lappend list1 6
puts [llength $list_name]
```

How can I understand after which command I need to use the $ sign with the variable name and when I do not need to use it?

Comment: I'm afraid the best answer is: read the docs => http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm -- pay attention to the examples

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is if Tcl is reading the value of a variable, use the `$`.
When modifying an existing variable, no `$` is used, the variable name is used.

- lappend directly modifies its argument, so it takes a variable name.
- lindex is reading the value of a list at some index, so the value of
  the list is used.
- llength is reading the value of a list, so the value
  of the list is used.

These three are actually fairly straightforward.   I find `lreplace` the most difficult to remember. `lreplace` returns a new list and does not modify the list given as an argument.  It accepts the value of the list as an argument.

Directly modifies the list:

- lappend
- lset

Uses the value of the list:

- lindex
- llength
- lreplace
- lmap
- lrange
- lreverse
- lsearch
- lsort

Comment: `foreach` is another command that uses list values.

Answer (score 2):

One of the conventions in the [tcl documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm) is to use *varName* or *typeVariable* for things that take a variable name and modify the contents of the variable, and *typeValue* or *type* (Like *list*, *string*, *dictionaryValue*) for things that take a value of that type. The latter case is when you use `$foo` to pass the contents of the variable. The first case is when you use `foo` (Unless of course the name of the variable you want to use is itself in a variable).

You also must be familiar with the [Dodekalogue](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Dodekalogue) if you're working with tcl, to know what the `$` means and how it can be used in general (Rule 8).